# In trying to win Karna over to the Pandava side, did Krishna suggest that Draupadi would accept him as her sixth husband?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, karna, draupadi

After Krishna's efforts to avert the Kurukshetra war fail, as one final attempt, he tries to win Karna over to the Pandava side, but in doing so, does Krishna suggest that Draupadi would accept Karna as her sixth husband?

Ganguli [translates](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05140.htm) [this verse](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs05138.htm) as:

> 15 rājanyā rājakanyāś cāpy ānayantv abhiṣecanam 
>       **ṣaṣṭhe ca tvāṃ tathā kāle draupady upagamiṣyati**

> Let queens and princesses bring golden and silver and earthen jars (full of water) and delicious herbs and all kinds of seeds and gems, and creepers, for thy installation. **During the sixth period, Draupadi also will come to thee (as a wife).**

An alternate translation from [here](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/21292/15F_Chapter_211.pdf) is:

> हिरण्मयांश्च ते कुम्भान् राजतान् पार्थिवांस्तथा। 
>  ओषध्यः सर्वबीजानि सर्वरत्नानि वीरुधः।।१४।। 
> राजन्या राजकन्याश्चाप्यानयन्त्वाभिषेचनम्॥१५॥ 
>  **षष्ठे त्वां च तथा काले द्रौपद्युपगमिष्यति।**

> Golden water pots as also silver and earthen ones (filled with water) and medicinal herbs and all sorts of seeds and gems, let the wives of kings and daughters of kings bring for your anointment (in the kingship). **During the sixth period Draupadi too will come to you as to a husband.**

What does "sixth period" in the above mean? And in what sense did Krishna say "will come to you" in the second line or verse?

Comment: The Pandavas had an arrangement where they would each have conjugal time with Draupadi for a certain period of time.  Krishna was suggesting the addition of a sixth period to that arrangement.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan That's a plausible explanation but it doesn't fit well with the first part of the verse which is talking about Karna's coronation in particular.

Comment: @sv. Why it is not in accordance with first verse? As they made that agreement and since Draupadi married Pancha Pandavas first, Krishna said he would be allotted sixth position.

Comment: @sv.  What doesn't fit well?  Krishna is saying that Karna will become the king and he will get to marry Draupadi, and a sixth conjugal period will be added to the other five.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan In verse 14 and first part of 15, Krishna is talking about anointment, in preparation for the coronation, so I think he means something in connection with the coronation ceremony itself.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes, that's what part of your answer says. Also, that's the whole point of Krishna trying to persuade Karna to leave Duryodhana (he was counting heavily on Karna to win the war for him) and join the Pandavas as their elder brother and take the throne.

Comment: @sv. Do you say Karna should be given priority to Dharmaraja in that agreement with Draupadi as Karna was elder? But question  here is, "did Krishna want to anoint Karna just because he was elder to Yudishtara or to persuade Karna to join the side of Pandavas or both"?

Comment: @Keshav Do you know why did Krsna use poor Draupadi as bait?

Comment: Maybe he was just giving Karna a offer that he knew he would refuse after all after this incident Krishan told Karna to advise Duryodhana the date of the Kurukshetra war and Karna accepted then.

Comment: Krishna didnt offered Draupadi... it was against dharma...It is very well mentioned i. Ramayana that the relation between the you and the wife of your younger brother is similar to that of Father and daughter... By dharama Drauprwas the daughter in law of Karna.. this was one of the reason that why shri rama killed Bali.

Answer (score 10):

The translation doesn't fit into the narrative. Before that sentence and after it, the whole narration is about coronation. To talk about Draupadi's marriage with Karna in between that topic is absurd. It would have been either before or after the coronation topic. Even the first part of that verse talks about queens and princesses bringing various items for coronation. So, how can that be followed suddenly by marriage?

The best translation I have heard by one Telugu scholar is this, which fits in with rest of the narration:

Sixth period means sixth part of the day, dusk (1.dawn, 2.morning, 3.noon, 4.afternoon, 5.evening, 6.dusk, 7.night). And dusk is considered the most auspicious time for activities like coronation. (perhaps that is the reason why Modi, being knowledgeable in such matters, took his oath as PM during that period of the day) So, Krishna was merely mentioning that Draupadi along with other queens and princesses would come to Karna's coronation. 
Moreover, Krishna very well knows the reason behind her having five husbands (Lord Shiva's boon etc.). He also knows how much she loathed Karna. So Krishna suggesting that Draupadi would marry Karna is an absurd notion.

Answer (score 8):

Sixth period means after five Pandavas. This is how [Bibek Debroy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibek_Debroy) translates [this verse](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/unic/mbh05_sa.html) (which is taken from [BORI critical version](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mahabharata-bori.html)).

> हिरण्मयांश्च ते कुम्भान्राजतान्पार्थिवांस्तथा |
>  ओषध्यः सर्वबीजानि
>   सर्वरत्नानि वीरुधः ||१४||
>
> राजन्या राजकन्याश्चाप्यानयन्त्वभिषेचनम् |
>   **षष्ठे च त्वां तथा काले द्रौपद्युपगमिष्यति** ||१५||
>
> The kings and princes who have gathered together in the cause of the
>   Pandavas and all the Andhakas and Vrishnis will grasp your feet. The
>   kings, the wives of kings and the daughters of kings will bring gold,
>   silver and earthen vessels, herbs, all kinds of seeds, all kinds of
>   gems and creepers for your anointment<sup>1</sup> **At the sixth point
>   in time**,<sup>2</sup> **Droupadi will have intercourse with you.**

Footnotes say 
<sup>1</sup> As King. 
<sup>2</sup> After the five Pandavas.

Comment: Well 'upagamishyati' literally means 'comes near'. I don't understand how Bibek Debroy translates it to 'have intercourse with'. Is he a reliable source?

Comment: @user1952500 one of the meanings of उपगम् = "to approach (a woman sexually)". In this context, his translation is correct. Check [here](http://andhrabharati.com/dictionary/sanskrit/index.php).

Comment: While that is true, the interpretation of context should be left to the reader and should not be done by the translator. Upagama also means to approach respectfully and many other things. For example, if I say that a devotee respectfully approaches the Devi, one should not think that the devotee approaches with sexual intent.

Comment: That said, I agree that the intent is the same. I don't agree with the translator adding the intent. It should be deduced by the reader.

Comment: And in that aspect, Ganguli's translation, while not adding anything, lets the user conclude the same meaning.

Comment: @user1952500 Dhatu "gam गम्" also means "approach to have sexual intercourse with". Check [here](http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/scans/MWScan/2014/web/webtc/indexcaller.php) and [here](http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/scans/AP90Scan/2014/web/webtc/indexcaller.php). In the above context (agreement of Pandavas), it is apt. There's nothing wrong in the above translation.

Comment: Well 'come' has many meanings in english as well and is contextual. Gam is used most commonly in the meaning of 'go'. Upa adds the meaning of 'near' to mean 'go near'. 
I don't want to make you not agree with the translator or his methods. It was just a comment for further readers of this answer that it is not the literal translation. They are free to choose what each means. Note that the question was about what Krishna meant, meaning what he meant in this context, and this answer tries to force what Krishna meant, while the Sanskrit language and Vyasa has left it ambiguous.

Comment: @user1952500 Obviously, "come near" you  doesn't make much sense . We need to understand context. Also, meanings of words in Sanskrit change with context (one can't apply literal meaning  of each Dhatu). If you go with this approach, probably you should comment on every translation.

Comment: Yes, but the question is about the correct meaning and Ganguli's translation does a good job. I have not read any work which translates this word into intercourse, but probably I am missing a whole world of subtext and double meanings out there.

Comment: BTW it's go near 'you' not Draupadi.

Comment: @user1952500 using the word "intercourse" is bit offensive. But It is alright, considering the agreement. But Gangulis translation is less offensive. But considering Dhatus and context, even this translation is good.

Comment: Draupadi spent a period of time as a 'wife' with each pandava. I doubt she was having intercourse for all of that while as a 'wife', or that she would start that period of time with intercourse. Hence I think the translation is for a very different demographic who want more spicy things from MBH.

Comment: Krishna didnt offered Draupadi... it was against dharma...It is very well mentioned i. Ramayana that the relation between the you and the wife of your younger brother is similar to that of Father and daughter... By dharama Draupadi was the daughter in law of Karna.. this was one of the reason that why shri rama killed Bali.

Answer (score 2):

> In trying to win Karna over to the Pandava side, did Krishna suggest that Draupadi would accept him as her sixth husband?

**Yes, here is what the famous medieval commentator [Kumarila Bhatta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kum%C4%81rila_Bha%E1%B9%AD%E1%B9%ADa) said:**

> The unlawful intercourse of the five Pandavas with a common wife has been very well explained by Vyasa himself: "Draupadi appeared, in full bloom of youth, out of the sacrificial altar, and as such she is Lakshmi herself [meaning just opulent; not actually Vishnu's wife, Lakshmi], consequently, she does not become tainted by her intercourse with many owners." To the same effect, we have also the following: "The Brahmarishi pointed out her wonderfully beautiful form to be superhuman, inasmuch as the great souled beautiful one (Draupadi) became younger day by day." All this tends to show that she was not an ordinary human being; and hence she has been spoken of as 'superhuman' (and as such her actions are not to be judged by the ordinary standard of human proprieties). **It is for this very same reason that Krishna himself promised to Karna that Draupadi would go to him on the sixth day (after having been with the Pandavas for 5 days). If it were not on account of the superhuman character of the woman, how could such an authoritative person as Krishna himself have promised such a transgression?**

Comment: Disagree.. it was against dharma...It is very well mentioned in Ramayana that the relation between the you and the wife of your younger brother is similar to that of Father and daughter... By dharama Draupadi the daughter in law of Karna.. this was one of the reason that why shri rama killed Bali.  Did Bhatta really wrote a commentary on Mahabharata i dont think so can you share me the work of Bhatta from which thia thing has been taken!!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem so.  Krishna had already told in Vana Parva to Draupadi that all her culprits (which includes karna) shall be punished & in Mahabharat Krishna says to Arjuna in BG that he has already killed Karna as Kaal, Arjuna is just an instrument.  Krishna even Critisizes Karna at the time of Karnas death as humiliating Draupadi. Hence it's not possible Krishna would offer Draupadi to her.  Now question comes is was this to just persuade karna? Well even this is not possible seeing the situation & context.

The entire verse has the context of Karna's Coronation as the king. The total description is of Coronation and no such word as "Intercourse" or "Wife" or any referrence to "Marriage" is there.   It's just mentioning that Various Persons in Mahabharat would be doing Various things in Coronation & mentions Draupadi also coming at 6th Period.  It's taking about she also getting involved in some kind of Ritual. The very next line Krishna is Talking about Yuddhisthir holding an umbrella behind Karna in the coronation. A reference of Draupadi being wife doesn't even make sense & has no such mention. It's totally mentioning performances of Rituals only.

Answer (score 1):

**Let's Analyze the whole thing**

Well the conclusion is that Krishna offering Draupadi is not only weird, contradictory, mismatch with the later and former verses but also against any sort of Dharma.

According to a majority of translators of the epic, Krishna did offered Karna to marry or have intercourse with Draupadi when he met Karna after the failure of peace mission.

This also gave rise to many speculation such as whether Karna was in love with Draupadi or vice versa.

There is folktale of Mango / Jambu episode which used to justify Krishna’s action on the ground that it was Draupadi who desired Karna.

Lets see what is the verse -

> *हिरण्मयांश्च ते कुम्भान् राजतान् पार्थिवांस्तथा। ओषध्यः सर्वबीजानि सर्वरत्नानि वीरुधः।।१४।। राजन्या राजकन्याश्चाप्यानयन्त्वाभिषेचनम्॥१५॥
> षष्ठे त्वां च तथा काले द्रौपद्युपगमिष्यति।*

As per translation by Kishor Mohan ganguli -

> All the kings and princes, again, that have been assembled for the
> Pandava-cause, and all the Andhakas and Vrishnis, will also embrace
> thy feet. Let queens and princesses bring golden and silver and
> earthen jars (full of water) and delicious herbs and all kinds of
> seeds and gems, and creepers, for thy installation. During the sixth
> period, Draupadi also will come to thee (as a wife). Let that best of
> Brahmanas, Dhaumya, of restrained soul, pour libations of clarified
> butter on the (sacred) fire, and let those Brahmanas regarding all the
> four Vedas as authoritative (and who are acting as priests unto the
> Pandavas), perform the ceremony of thy installation.
>
> Ref - Udyoga Parva: Bhagwat Yana Parva: Section CXL

So KMG translation tells us - ‘During the sixth period, Draupadi also will come to thee (as a wife). ’
Here (as a wife) is KMG’s own interpretation.

***Actual translated line is - ‘During the sixth period, Draupadi also will come to thee’.***

As per Translation of the BORI Critical edition done by Bibek debroy -

> The kings, the wives of kings and the daughters of kings will bring
> gold, silver and earthen vessels, herbs, all kinds of seeds, all kinds
> of gems and creepers for your anointment.4 At the sixth point in
> time,5 Droupadi will have intercourse with you. Let the brahmanas who
> are acquainted with the four Vedas consecrate you today, assisted by
> the priest of the Pandavas,6 the five Pandava brothers who are bulls
> among men, Droupadi’s five sons, the Panchalas and the Chedis. You
> will be seated on the skin of a tiger.
>
> Bibek Debroy. The Mahabharata: Volume 4 (pp. 504-505). Penguin Books
> Ltd. Kindle Edition.

Where as Bibek debroy tells us - ‘At the sixth point in time,5 Droupadi will have intercourse with you’

I won’t tell that above translators translated wrongly.

Sanskrit words have various meaning depending on the contexts.

Theres one more translation!!!

> Golden water pots as also silver and earthen ones (filled with water)
> and medicinal herbs and all sorts of seeds and gems, let the kings and
> daughters of kings bring for your anointment (in the kingship)at the
> (Shashti kal)the sixth part of the day and Draupadi also will come to
> you (and will take part in yhe coronation ceremony)

The analysis---

Both the verses speak about the coronation procedure. They are interlinked as they both are meant to elaborate the way it would happen.

**What is Shashti Kaal?**

Shukla Shashti is the name for the 6th Tithi (lunar day). It's the 6th Tithi of Shuklapaksha. It's nature is Yasha Prada,( offers fame) which can be interpreted as "one that gives fame".

It's good for following works: house, land; service social customs; market & marketing, trade, sale - purchase; art; painting of sculpture; wood work; war, deeds related to Pitris (ancestors); jewellery; clothes designing, oil massage; donation and welfare; actions related to water.

The most classical texts Jyotisha Ratnakara,Muhurta Chintamani, Poorva Kalamrita and Brihat Samhita tell the auspiciousness Of Shashti kaal.Karttikeya presides over this day. It is favorable for coronations, meeting new friends, festivities and enjoyment.

The other 2 translations doesn't fit into the narrative.

Before that sentence and after it, the whole narration is about coronation. To talk about Draupadi's intimacy with Karna in between that topic is absurd.
Even the first part of that verse talks about queens and princesses bringing various items for coronation.
So, how can that be followed suddenly by Draupadi 's approval of him as her husband?

**KMG translates this as "During the sixth period, Draupadi will also come to thee (as a wife).”**

Sixth period means sixth part of the day, dusk (1.dawn, 2.morning, 3.noon, 4.afternoon, 5.evening, 6.dusk, 7.night). And dusk is considered the most auspicious time for activities like coronation.

So, Krishna was merely mentioning that Draupadi along with other queens and princesses would come to Karna's coronation.
Krishna ascertains Draupadi's presence because she is the First Lady of Pandava Family.

The animosity between her and Karna during dyutsabha may make Karna apprehensive of her reaction if he enters as the Eldest and King to be.

**the word - ‘उपगम’. It has several meaning -
Agreement, Approach, Intercourse, Veneration, Approaching respectfully, promise, undergoing etc.
[Ref - Sanskrit Dictionary for Spoken Sanskrit]**

So we have to pick the word contextually.
Now if you look at KMG or Bibek debroy translation the 3rd translation is actually right in saying -

“Before that sentence and after it, the whole narration is about coronation. To talk about Draupadi's intimacy with Karna in between that topic is absurd. ”

For example take the Debory’s translation -

> “The kings, the wives of kings and the daughters of kings will bring
> gold, silver and earthen vessels, herbs, all kinds of seeds, all kinds
> of gems and creepers for your anointment.
>
> **At the sixth point in time,Droupadi wistrong textll have intercourse with you**.
>
> Let the brahmanas who are acquainted with the four Vedas consecrate
> you today, assisted by the priest of the Pandavas,6 the five Pandava
> brothers who are bulls among men, Droupadi’s five sons, the Panchalas
> and the Chedis. You will be seated on the skin of a tiger.”

The first line and the third line speaks on coronation of Karna where as in middle it speaks on Draupadi having intercourse with Karna.

So the translation done by Debroy even if correct in line by line translation, It misfits if some one see it contextually.
Now before going to We also need to understand few things -

Karna was grandfather when the meeting was happening -

> He got the brahmanas to name me Vasushena. O Keshava! When I attained
> youth, he had me married to wives. O Janardana! I have given birth to
> sons and grandsons through them. O Krishna! My heart is tied with
> bonds of affection to them.
>
> Bibek Debroy. The Mahabharata: Volume 4 (p. 506). Penguin Books Ltd.
> Kindle Edition.

On the other hand Abhimanyu was like son to Draupadi got married to Uttara just before that.

At that point of time both parties were staring at war knowing fully that it’s going to cause immense destruction.

Krishna’s mission was fully political.

If he was there to forge a romantic angle he could have done it long back.

Neither Karna or Draupadi expressed any desire for each other in entire canonical text of Sanskrit epic.

If we say Krishna said that because Draupadi gave the consent to Krishna, then you are pretty wrong in assessing the whole thing.

There was no indication in Mahabharata that Krishna took Draupadi’s consent before offering such thing.

In case Krishna really wanted Karna to marry Draupadi, the consent of Kunti, Vyas, Yudisthira or Drupada was the actually needed.

Second point is - Krishna didn’t made only that offer. He made many offer to Karna and lets see those offers -

**Holding the white chamara in his hand for fanning, Yudhishthira, the son of Kunti, would ride on the same car behind him.
After his installation is over, the mighty Bhimasena, would hold the white umbrella over his head.
Arjuna then would then drive his car furnished with a hundred tinkling bells, its sides covered with tiger-skins, and with white steeds harnessed to it.
Nakula and Sahadeva, and the five sons of Draupadi, and the Panchalas with that mighty car-warrior Sikhandin, all would proceed behind him.**

**Krishna himself, with all the Andhakas and the Vrishnis, would walk behind him.**

Now shall we say Krishna took consent of Yudisthira, Bhima, Arjuna, Nakula, Sahadeva, Abhimanyu, Satyaki or five sons of Draupadi before making the above statement?

Or they secretly wanted to do above thing?

-

**

- **

  - As far as Draupadi was concerned, she took Karna’s name thrice    altogether in the  epic.
    **

**

Out of them two before war and another was after war.

Lets see those statements -

> My grief at Karna's ridicule is incapable of being assuaged! On these
> grounds I deserve to be ever protected by thee, O Kesava, viz., our
> relationship, thy respect (for me), our friendship, and thy lordship
> (over me)
>
> Ref - Vana Parva: Arjunabhigamana Parva: Section XII

Another time she took Karna’s name to make a point to Yudisthira why he shouldn’t forgive his enemies -

> Having brought thee who deservest to enjoy every happiness and never
> such woe, into such distress, alas, that wicked-minded and sinful
> wretch joyeth with his friends! O Bharata, when dressed in deer-skin
> thou hast set out for the woods, only four persons, O monarch, viz.,
> Duryodhana, Karna, the evil-minded Sakuni, and Dussasana that bad and
> fierce brother of Duryodhana, did not shed tears! With the exception
> of these, O thou best of the Kurus, all other Kurus filled with sorrow
> shed tears from their eyes!
>
> Ref - Vana Parva: Arjunabhigamana Parva: Section XXVII

In fact she asked Yudisthira to kill his enemies -

> “That Kshatriya, O son of Pritha, who discovereth not his energy when
> the opportunity cometh, is ever disregarded by all creatures!
> Therefore, O king, thou shouldst not extend thy forgiveness to the
> foe. Indeed, with thy energy, without doubt, thou, mayst slay them
> all! So also, O king, that Kshatriya who is not appeased when the time
> for forgiveness cometh, becometh unpopular with every creature and
> meeteth with destruction both in this and the other world!”
>
> Ref - Vana Parva: Arjunabhigamana Parva: Section XXVII

When Krishna was leaving for Peace Mission, Draupadi spoke the following words to Krishna -

> O Dasharha! You know what Yudhishthira told Sanjaya. You have heard
> everything. ‘O immensely radiant one!23 O father! O mighty-armed one!
> Give us five villages—Kushasthala, Vrikasthala, Masandi, Varanavata
> and whichever other village you decide as the fifth and the last, for
> us to live in.’ O Keshava! Duryodhana and his advisers were to be
> addressed in these words. O Krishna! O Dasharha! Yudhishthira was
> modest and desired peace. But though he heard these words, Suyodhana
> did not comply.24 O Krishna! If Suyodhana desires peace without
> returning the kingdom, there is no point in going there to strive for
> peace. O mighty-armed one! Together with the Srinjayas, the Pandavas
> are capable of withstanding the terrible and angry forces of
> Dhritarashtra’s son. Our objectives are incapable of being obtained
> through conciliation and generosity. O Madhusudana! **Therefore, you
> should not show any compassion towards them. O Krishna! If we wish to
> save our lives, enemies who cannot be pacified through conciliation
> and generosity should be chastised through the staff. O Achyuta! O
> mighty-armed one! Therefore, swiftly hurl a mighty staff at them,
> together with the Pandavas and the Srinjayas. The Parthas are capable
> of doing this** and it will bring you fame. O Krishna! Do what will
> bring happiness to the kshatriyas. O Dasharha! If a kshatriya follows
> his own dharma, he should kill a kshatriya who has become avaricious,
> and even a non-kshatriya.
>
> Bibek Debroy. The Mahabharata: Volume 4 (pp. 374-375). Penguin Books
> Ltd. Kindle Edition.

- **As far as Arjuna was concerned, Krishna himself stated the below thing -**

> “Then in that hall, while Krishna stood, the charioteer's son
> addressed her in the presence of her fathers-in-law saying, 'O
> Daughter of Drupada thou hast no refuge. Better betake thyself as a
> bond-woman to the house of Dhritarashtra's son.Thy husbands, being
> defeated, no longer exist. Thou hast a loving soul, choose some one
> else for thy lord.' This speech, proceeding from Karna, was a wordy
> arrow, sharp, cutting all hopes, hitting the tenderest parts of the
> organisation, and frightful. It buried itself deep in Arjuna's heart.”
>
> [Ref - Udyoga Parva: Section XXIX]
> also note that Arjuna had vow to kill Karna.

- *As far as Yudisthira is concern, he makes an important statement when he comes to know about Karna identity* -

> “If I had both Karna and Arjuna for aiding me, I could have vanquished
> Vasudeva himself. ”
>
> Ref - Santi Parva: Rajadharmanusasana Parva: Section I

- Well it doesn’t seems to be like Yudisthira speaking of giving up
  throne even after coming to know about Karna’s identity.

  Therefore it could be easily proven that angle of consent for what
  Krishna spoke to Karna doesn’t even appears any where.

  So it would be pretty ridiculous to think any romantic angle at that
  point of time given the context of the situation.
- **Krishna promised Draupadi the following thing -**

> Vaisampayana continued, 'In that assembly of heroes Vasudeva then
> spake unto the weeping Draupadi as follows, 'O fair lady, the wives of
> those with whom thou art angry, shall weep even like thee, beholding
> their husbands dead on the ground, weltering in blood and their bodies
> covered with the arrows of Vivatsu! Weep not, lady, for I will exert
> to the utmost of my powers for the sons of Pandu! I promise thou shalt
> (once more) be the queen of kings!
>
> Ref - Vana Parva: Arjunabhigamana Parva: Section XXVII

Here Krishna makes a clear cut promise that her enemies would die and Draupadi would be queen of King again.

- Now there was few options for Karna - He has to write off himself
  from the list of enemies of Pandavas.

  Which means either he has to stay back or join Pandavas.

  If he backs off from war people would definitely say him a coward.

  Or he has to fight and die.

**An objection can be raised that Krishn promised that Draupadi will become queen again and it is possible by màrying her to Karna and making him King. Even though I already mentioned that Yudhishthira showing any sign of giving up the throne waas noit mentioned even after knowing the identity but still lets say that Krishna offered Draupadi**

But again the counter question may rise in the case of marriage between Karna and Draupadi -

**Can an elder brother marry wife of Younger brother???**

Lets see

- **As per Dharma-Shastras** -

> **57. The wife of an elder brother is for his younger (brother) the wife of a Guru; but the wife of the younger is declared (to be) the
> daughter-in-law of the elder.**
>
> 58. An elder (brother) who approaches the wife of the younger, and a younger (brother who approaches) the wife of the elder, except in
>     times of misfortune, both become outcasts, even though (they were
>     duly) authorised.
> 59. On failure of issue (by her husband) a woman who has been authorised, may obtain, (in the) proper (manner prescribed), the
>     desired offspring by (cohabitation with) a brother-in-law or (with
>     some other) Sapinda (of the husband). [Niyoga - Rule]

Note this-- The relation between Karna and Draupadi was of Father and daughter-in-law. Any relation between them was highly prohibited!!! Expect in the case of Niyog. And the situation was far-far-away from Niyog.

- So as per law clear that relation between woman her elder brother in
  law as father in law and vice - versa.

  Niyoga allows an elder brother in law to have sex with younger sister
  in law for saving the family line. But that has many conditions and
  has to go through many rites.

Now does this rule has scriptual proof??

In Ramayana one of the reason to kill bali was this.

> न च ते मर्षये पापम् क्ष्त्रियो अहम् कुलोद्गतः | औरसीम् भगिनीम् वा अपि
> भार्याम् वा अपि अनुजस्य यः || ४-१८-२२ प्रचरेत नरः कामात् तस्य दण्डो
> वधः स्मृतः |
>
> "As a Kshatriya emerged from a best dynasty I do not tolerate your
> wrongdoing, and the punishment to the one who lustfully indulges with
> his daughter, or with his sister, or with the wife of his younger
> brother is his elimination, as recalled from scriptures (Dhrama-Shastras).

**Kunti’s statement calling Dritarastra as Father in Law** -

> O brave one! You have to bear the burden of the Kuru lineage now. I
> will dwell in the forest now and devote myself to serving my
> father-in-law and mother-in-law.65 I will dwell with Gandhari, cover
> myself with filth and devote myself to austerities.”
>
> The Mahabharata: Volume 10 (Kindle Locations 9568-9570). Penguin Books
> Ltd. Kindle Edition.

--- Credit goes to the researchers

Well there are many more points bot i think its more than sufficient to say that Krishna offering Draupadi is not only weird, contradictory, mismatch with the later and former verses but also against any sort of Dharma.

Hence my honest conclusion is that he didn't offered anything to Karna.

Well no one knows what actually shri krishna wanted to say. One may even say that the it was upto the Karna what he extract and its upto.

**Shri Krishna was offering nothing to the Karna!!!**

Maybe not even throne--
Question- How you can say so!!
Answer- Karna had no roght over throne. Karna becoming the heir would have been full of challenging.

Question-But wasnt Karna the eldest.
Ans-Yes.

But Karna was never entitled for throne— He was Konteya not Pandav.

Pandavas' claim to the throne was derived from Pandu not Kunti, through the act of Niyoga. A man if rendered incapable to reproduce because of death or other reasons( in this case the reason being that inconvenient curse put on Pandu) can adopt a son of his wife by another. The child will have rights to all his adoptive father's incomes and lands.

The most important thing is consent by the adoptive father. If that father is dead, as in the case of Vichitraveer, then the decision has to be made collectively by his wives and his family members. Kunti was not even queen when she brought forth Karna, so how does he have any claim to Pandu’s throne? And Pandu never adopted Karna.

Hence, he had no right over Throne.

**This is again proved by the words of Yudhisthira“If I had both Karna and Arjuna for aiding me, I could have vanquished Vasudeva himself.**

Shri Krishna was just playing mind games with the Karna.

Doesn't matter whether Karna say Yes or No. Nothing will change.

**Sanjay had clearly said that pandavas are the intrument to kill Adharama. Karna was the incarnation of a evil asura-- mentioned in Mahabharata and he was meant to be killed by Nara. Arjuna was reincarnation of Nara.**

It is very well mentioned in Mahabharata that Krishna can destroy everything with his mind alone. That good tactician was Shri Krishna.

The visit of Krishna to hastinapura was a beautiful depiction of that where he played with the mind of everyone

Thats it!!!

Comment: Amazing sir how awesome you need to answer more questions can you answer a few for me?

Comment: Yes...sure ...if i can i will

Comment: What is Dasa and what were their treatments in puranic literature? Does Brahmacharini mean female scholar if so is there any proof of female scholarship?  Suggestions for learning Sanskrit on my own?

Comment: @Haridasa. Dasa can have multiple of meaning depending on the context... it can be reffered to a servant, labour under someone. Or even in a pious way like i am a dasa of bhagvan. Dasa are not slaves.. Its written in Arthshstra that it ia illegal to force a dasa to do certain types of work, to hurt or abuse him, or to force sex on a female dasa.... Whereas you can do anything to a slave... One of the reason that why when when greeks came to India they mentioned that there is no slavery in India.

Comment: @Haridasa AOMI there is no word for  "slave" is absent in Sanskrit. Remember in MHB when Pandavas loosed themselves and draupadi then Duryodhana humilated them this was an adharma. Even though they become there dasa but that didnt gave them right to treat as they wish.... Thats why that act was called a very big Adharma.

Comment: @Haridasa about women scholar then yes...for this you dont have to refer the Purans.... Many of the Vedic hymns were revealed by females... Vedas clearly mention female actively taking part in debates and all... Some of the name are Gargi, Maitri, Vak, etc.... there are many.... About Sanskrit then i myself is not that great in sanskrit...but for the initial you can take help of youtube... but i will advice you to take admission in sankrit in a proper school be it traditional or not. And learn it through your mother tongue not english!!!  And yes there is difference b/w modernbday Sanskrit

Comment: Okay sir thanks for information.