# Is it true that the sixth period of king is pattabhishekam(Crowning)?

Tags: astrology, tradition, kings

According to jyotish shastra (astrology), is it true that sixth period of a king refers to the time of pattabhishekam(Crowning)?

Comment: Couldn't understand what u meant by "the 6th period of the king"

Comment: Like the division of periods the of the day as the first part, second part etc., the sixth period refers to the particular time or period of time. @Rickross

Comment: You mean the 6th phase of a king's rule?

Comment: @Rickross 6th phase seems okay, but the word *king's rule* says that he was crowned (already). So it may not be the division of time I'm searching for.

Comment: @Rickross actually the sixth phase or sixth period (of time) has to be crowning phase...

Comment: Okay so do u know what are the previous five phases?

Comment: @Rickross No, I heard it from preachings. I need to know from which book it has been taken.

Comment: It is sixth part of the day (evenings) which is fit for doing coronation ceremonies. See https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21325/5212.  That is why Krishna says we Draupadi will come to Karna. That was mistranslated by many as "coming to Karna as wife".

Comment: proofs? As I know, almost 20 translators translated that verse as "in the sixth period, Droupadi will come to you as a wife" but it was also translated for her to have sex with Karna.

KMG for example has the translation that Droupadi will come to Karna as a wife, while BORI contains the verse that she will have sex with Karna. Also, how can that be a translation error?

Comment: @GabrielAlexanderGonzalezAgu translations must be straight if they have the commentator's views on them, then there is bias.

Answer (score 0):

In short the Answer is yes..
The division of day is vedy much in hindu scriptures.

As per the kala vibhajana, “chaturtha kala (fourth time)” is when people should eat food (this is present in aruna prashna of yajurveda).

When Hanuman meets sita he tells her that Rama out of grief for her is not earing lunch on time and he is delaying it and eating in panchama kala (fifth time).

All these kala related terminology is technical terminology of scriptures, where jyotisha is used. Jyotisha is a Vedanga- Limb of Vedas.

So shahta kala(sixth time) is considered to be an auspicious time. It's nature is Yasha Prada,( offers fame) which can be interpreted as "one that gives fame".

Yes.. the condutiom of coronation ritual in shasta kala is considered to be auspicious.